# Python error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b Usuarios.csv' does not exist: b Usuarios.csv'"

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, spyder

I'm using pandas to read a csv file, the code runs pretty well when I run it on Spyder, but then, when I try running it on anaconda prompt or even double clicking on the .py file it does not run. On anaconda prompt I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b Usuarios.csv' does not exist: b Usuários.csv'" error, even if the file does exists and it is there in the same directory as the .py file. I am using this code:

```
import pandas 
import csv

csv_reader = pandas.read_csv("D:\\clovi\\Projetos\\Python\\Usuarios.csv",encoding='utf-8')

j=0
y = csv_reader.iloc[-1].values[0]

while True:
    i=0
    x = csv_reader.iloc[j].values
    usuario = x[i]
    i+=1
    pase = x[i]
    j+=1
    if usuario == y:
        edistribucion(usuario,pase)
        break
    else:
        edistribucion(usuario,pase)
```

**NOTE:** For reading the file, I also tried doing

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

csv_reader = pd.read_csv("Usuarios.csv")

.
.
.
```

As I said, it runs well when I'm running on Spyder, but it doesn't run anywhere else. What am I doing wrong on the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the Anaconda prompt does not have permission to access the directory where the CSV file is located. In that case you could modify your script to accept a command-line argument, and if there is none, default to the path you already have, something like this:

```
import sys
import os
import pandas 
import csv

# If there is a command-line argument, and the argument is a valid file, this matches
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    csv_path = sys.argv[1]
else:
    csv_path = r'D:\clovi\Projetos\Python\Usuarios.csv'

csv_reader = pandas.read_csv(csv_path,encoding='utf-8')

j=0
y = csv_reader.iloc[-1].values[0]

while True:
    i=0
    x = csv_reader.iloc[j].values
    usuario = x[i]
    i+=1
    pase = x[i]
    j+=1
    if usuario == y:
        edistribucion(usuario,pase)
        break
    else:
        edistribucion(usuario,pase)
```

You'd be able to dynamically change the CSV without breaking the code, so in the command-line:

```
# This tries to process the hard-coded CSV
python clovis_magno.py

# While this processes top_secret_data.csv in your Desktop
python clovis_magno.py "C:\Users\Clovis Magno\Desktop\top_secret_data.csv"
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!! now it runs when I execute it in Anaconda Prompt, but I still have some issues executing that by double clicking on .py file, I can solve it later, though

Comment: I can try to help you out with that too.

Comment: The thing with the double click to open the script is that you need to add a shebang at the top of the script, and AFAIK you cannot pass command-line arguments like the path to your CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Type in Spyder CLI:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Go to the resulting directory in Anaconda Prompt:

```
cd path\from\Spyder\print
```

Now launch your script. You may copy it to the directory or call by path.

Comment: I also tried doing that, but the path I get is the same I put in Anaconda Prompt. I also noticed that I get the same error in all codes I'm reading .csv files, but, again, they run well on Spyder or even Visual Studio